# An issue of dependent and independent random variables involving geometric Brownian motion.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $X(t)=X(0)e^{\mu t + \sigma Z(t)}$ be a geometric Brownian motion (GBM) where $Z(t)$ is the standard Brownian motion with drift $0$ and the variance rate per unit of time is $1$. Now, let $s<t$ then I found in some of the text books that $X(t)$ and $X(s)$ are dependent random variables but $X(s)/X(0)$ and $X(t)/X(s)$ are independent random variables, but I don't understand why this is the case.

Comment: Note that X(t)/X(s) is a function of Z(t)-Z(s) and that X(s)/X(0) is a function of Z(s)-Z(0). Now, what do you know about the increments Z(t)-Z(s) and Z(s)-Z(0) of Brownian motion Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0<s<t$ then $Z(s)-Z(0)$ and $Z(t)-Z(s)$ are independent because the intervals $(0,s)$ and $(s,t)$ do not overlap.

Call these $A$ and $B$:
\begin{align}
A & = Z(s)-Z(0), \\
B & = Z(t)-Z(s).
\end{align}
Then $A,B$ are independent random variables.

But 
\begin{align}
A & = Z(s) - Z(0) \\
A+B & = Z(t) - Z(0)
\end{align}
are not independent.

And the same applies to functions of $A$ and $B$, such as an exponential function.

Comment: Sorry but this hardly explains the *reason* why these are independent, does it?

Comment: @Did : It explains how independence of the quotients mentioned in the question follows from independence of these increments.  Independence of increments is part of the definition of Brownian motion as I understand it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thus "Independence of increments" should be mentioned somewhere in the post.